# Tangents are drawn to the parabola $y^2=4x$ from the point P (6,5) to the touch the parabola at Q and R.

Tags: conic-sections

> $C_1$ is the circle which touches the parabola at Q and $C_2$ is the circle which touches the parabola at R. Both circles pass through the focus of the parabola. Find the radius of circle $C_2$

The equation of tangent to the parabola 
$$y=mx+\frac am$$
$$5=6m+\frac 1m$$
$$m=\frac 12 , \frac 13$$

Therefore, equation of tangents will be 
$$x-2y+4=0$$ and $$x-3y+9$$

The point of intersections with the parabola $y^2=4x$ were found out to be $(4,4)$ and $(9,6)$

Let R be $(9,6)$. Hence circle $C_2$ passes through (9,6) and focus (1,0)

This data isn’t enough to find the radius of the circle. How do I get more information?

Comment: for x=6, y=4.89≈5. how can we draw two tangents from a point on the parabola? But the tangent on parabola is  also tangent on circle and the center of circle is on the  perpendicular bisector of line passing points (9, 6) and (1, 0).

Comment: @sirous what are you implying. I can’t figure out what you are trying to say

Comment: You say two tangents are drawn from point (6, 5). but this point is almost on the curve because it coordinates satisfy the equation of parabola. from this point only on tangent can be drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If the equation of $C_2$ is $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$$

$$(1-h)^2+(0-k)^2=r^2=(9-h)^2+(6-k)^2\implies8(2h-10)+6(2k-6)\ \ \ \  (1)$$

Again,  the gradient of $C_2$ at$(9,6)$

$$=-\dfrac{9-h}{6-k}$$  which should be $=$ the gradient of the parabola at $(9,6)$  $$\dfrac{4}{2\cdot6}$$

Solve for $h,k$

Comment: Why are the gradients equal? Also why is the does the gradient expression $-\frac{9-h}{6-k}$ have a negative sign in front of it?

Comment: @Aditya, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846896/how-do-we-know-when-two-curves-touch-each-other

Answer (score 0):

By [homogenization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4128569/688539), $$Yy - 2X - 2x=0 \tag{1}$$ is the equation for tangent of parabola at $(x,y)$, plug $(6,5)=(X,Y)$ into this:

$$ 5y -2x=12 \tag{2}$$

The above is the equation of the chord of contact, we now find the intersection of the above equation with the parabola $y^2-4x=0$, by manipulation, we find an equation in $y$:

$$(y-6)(y-4) = 0 \tag{3}$$

From the above, we find the point where the chord cuts the parabola are $(x,y) = \{ (9,6) , (4,4)\}$, plugging these points into $(1)$:

$$ 3Y-X-9=0 ; (x,y)=(9,6)\tag{4}$$
$$ 2Y- X-4=0 ; (x,y) = (4,4)\tag{5}$$

[By Family of circles tangent to a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2451277/688539) at each point:

$$ (x-9)^2 +(y-6)^2 + \lambda( 3Y-X-9) =0; (x,y)=(9,6)$$

$$ (x-4)^2 + (y-4)^2 + \lambda' (2Y-X-4)=0; (x,y) = (4,4)$$

Upon substitution of the focal point $(1,0)$ we find $\lambda= 10$ and $\lambda'=5$, hence the radius can be calculated by standard result as $\frac{5 \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $ 5 \sqrt{10}$

Answer (score -1):

Find the equation of both the circles using $S+kL=0$.

$L$ is the equation of the tangent to the parabola at points of contact. Point of contact may be considered as point circles.

Since point of contact comes out to be $(4,4)$ and $(9,6)$ and the equation of tangents are: $2y=x+4$ and $3y=x+9$

Circle through $(9,6)$ is $(x-9)^2+(y-6)^2+k(3y-x-9)=0$

Since it passes through the focus $(1,0)$, therefore, putting the values of $X$ and $Y$ we get $K=10$.

Hence the equation comes out to be:
$(x-9)^2+(y-6)^2+10(3y-x-9)=0$
or $x^2+y^2-28x+18y+108=0$

Similarly, for the second circle through $(4,4)$: $(x-4)^2+(y-4)^2+k(2y-x-4)=0$

Since it passes through $(1,0)$ we get $K$ as $5$. We have got both the circles and we can find the radius.

Using this method we get the centre of circles as $(13/2,-1)$ and $(14,-9)$.

Therefore using the centres and the point $(1,0)$ we can get the radius using the distance formula.

$r_1$ comes out to be $\sqrt{125/4}$ and $r_2$ comes out to be $\sqrt{250}$.